# Reading Digital and Analog Signal from Different Sources with Arduino

Tags: arduino, digital-logic, analog, ground, ground-loop

I am using an Arduino to read signals from 2 different devices. (This is an automotive project so all 3 are powered by the 12v battery of the car).

The signal from one of the devices is a digital High/Low - where Low is 0v and High is 5V (I've verified this with a meter).

The signal from the other device produces a 0v min, 8.4v max square wave. I am using a 1k and 1.5k resistor to drop the square wave to 0-5v in order to safely read the analog signal with the Arduino. I am using the [FreqMeasure](https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/FreqMeasure) library to read the frequency of the square wave so since that library requires the input to be pin 8 of the Arduino, that's where the output of the voltage divider is going.

Here is the schematic for the input of the circuit: 
[image]

The "RADIO_INPUT" of the schematic is the analog signal via a 3.5mm jack. The "BACKUP_INPUT" is the digital signal also via a 3.5mm jack.

When only 1 of the inputs are connected (for example: just the digital signal, or just the analog signal) everything works exactly how I expect.

But when both of the inputs are connected I get results that I wasn't expecting. I plugged in an oscilloscope to Pin 8 and Ground of the Arduino and when the digital connection was plugged in the analog signal goes to a 2-5v range instead of 0-5v. As soon as I unplug the digital signal it goes back to the 0-5v range as expected.

On the other side, when I connect the oscilloscope to the digital input I read the same analog frequency as I see from the analog signal except in the 0-2v range. Again when I unplug the analog input the digital input works exactly as expected and I just see the 0v Low, 5v High signal.

What appears to be happening is that the signals are somehow contaminating each other but I don't understand why. I assume that there's a problem connecting the grounds but I'm not sure what to do to keep the signals separated.

So my question is: is there anything I need to do to somehow isolate these 2 different signals so that they don't effect each other? Or am I missing something fundamental with reading in these 2 different kinds of signals?

Thanks!

Comment: Your grounds look OK as drawn but I suspect that there is a power-supply problem and you haven't shown any details of it. Update the schematic showing the car battery, voltage regulator and decoupling capacitors.

Comment: Just to be clear, does the circuit work when the oscilloscope is **not** connected to it? Are you certain that the "grounds" of both of your inputs are actually connected to the chassis?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I have pulled out one of the cigarette lighter plugs and am using that as the power source of the two devices. So I don't think they are connected to the chassis but to the battery ground. I have tried powering the Arduino through the 12v port from the same source and also from my computer usb with the same results. I get the same results with the oscilloscope disconnected.

Comment: @Transistor There is no voltage regulator or decoupling capacitors. What would the decoupling capacitors be for?

Comment: The Arduino microprocessor runs on a 5 V supply so there has to be a voltage regulator to run it from the 12 V vehicle battery. The fact that you think there is none suggests that you are using the built-in regulator. The capacitors will protect against noise and provide voltage regulation stability. Many new users treat them as a kind of optional extra so I usually ask to see them.